# ActiveX reuse browser client certificate

Tags: browser, activex, certificate, smartcard

situation is as follows - client uses smart card authetication against server (F5 server actualy). There is need for ActiveX component, which would collect some data from client's computer and then upload to server. Problem is, that server is very protected and allows only those connection, which have valid client certificate. Is there a way for ActiveX component to get that certificate, which was used for opening page, on which component resides? Or maybe it is possible to reuse browser connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have found solution. It ain't perfect but it works. On server side I read client certificate thumbprint and include that on webpage. ActiveX component later on reads thumbprint from html and then locates certificate with same thumbprint in user certificate store. Works well with smart-card as well! :)
Instead of thumbprint one can use something else, like certificate subject, but thumbprint is most unique one.
nice one!

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveX control, running in IE, can use WinINET to make its HTTPS connections. Those connections will use the client certificate that IE is using. Alternatively, you could simply have the AX control provide the data to HTML/script and have that content do the network traffic.

Comment: Only I guess WinINET is something historical. What are good ways to doing this today from C# .NET?

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example. I tried using WebRequest class, but it did not include client sertificate in request.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "historical". WinINET is the network stack used by most Microsoft client applications. Writing ActiveX controls in .NET is strongly discouraged.